# Create a new cshtml page in MVC project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC website project to design it , I don't have any knowledge about MVC coding :( . All I want to do that create new .cshtml page in (views/home) folder, which will be welcoming page (or new home page), and display this page before the existing page (home/index) which will open by link or button in my new home page.
Please, I want to knew method.. step by step .
Note: the developer gave me a beta link of site which don't contain a many folders like (Models , Controllers , App_Start , ...).

I hope It's clear,
Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you can create new Action in Home controller. Right click on this Action and create view for this ActionResult Newpage.

```
public ActionResult NewPage()
{
  return View();
}
```

change RouteConfig.cs file under App_Start folder like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Default",
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "NewPage", id =    UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

now build your application and run your project. Do you learn more about MVC CRUD?

Comment: the developer gave me a beta link of site which don't contain a many of main folders like (Models , Controllers , App_Start , ...) ! what can i do??

Comment: Just follow this given links. They have given very good tutorial.                                                         http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0):

You can change the default homepage in App_Start > RouteConfig.cs. 
Change its controller and action to your welcoming page.
In your welcoming page, just set up a button that redirects the page to your homepage.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) ,,, but unfortunately, the developer gave me a beta copy of  site which don't contain a many of main folders like (Models , Controllers , App_Start , ...) ! what can i do??

Comment: Your .csproj should have information about the files included in the project including the main folders you mentioned. MVC web applications obviously won't work without the model, view and controller folders. Maybe it is hidden. Try clicking 'show all files' icon in the solution explorer.